# Does h.264 levels affect the quality of the output?

Tags: ffmpeg, encoding, h.264, mpeg

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H.264/MPEG-4_AVC#Levels), the example for high resolution of level 4.0 is 2048x1024@30fps. But the resolution of the video ready to encode is 1280x960, which is about level 3.2. 
Is it better to set the level to 4.0 even though the level I should set is 3.2? Does levels affect the quality of the output? Or it just a reference?

Comment: As that table shows, the levels define the max settings, so higher levels should include everything below them.  You're probably better using the lowest level that meets your needs to have the greatest compatibility (not all decoders will support all levels).

Comment: The level is merely just a flag in the H.264 bitstream. All that matters is the actual video bitrate.